# how to import one variable value from one function to another function in flask

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,session
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
import Distilbert as d
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd



app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/" , methods = ["GET","POST"])
def hello():
    return render_template("index.html")



@app.route("/su", methods = ["GET","POST"])
def data_value():
    data = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        context = request.form['context']
        question= request.form['question']
        data.append(d.Question_answer(context,question))

    df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Context', 'Question', 'Answer'])
    Insert_data(df)
    return render_template("home.html", td = data)
    

@app.route("/data", methods = ["GET","POST"])
def Insert_data(df):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            d.insert_into_db(df, cursor) 
            print('parsed using normal parsing1_div .')

        except Exception as ex:
            print('db fail1 ')
            print(ex)
        return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In this code I want to import df variable value from data_value function to Insert_data function I am using this code and i am getting error TypeError: Insert_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df' , df is a dataframe i want to insert this value into database(SQL).

Comment: Do you need a POST request to /su to insert df to the SQL? or are you looking to insert df with a post request to /data?

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route("/su", methods = ["GET","POST"])
def data_value():
    ...
    Insert_data(df) # IF Insert_data(df) works? 
    #This code block will go render_template("index.html")
    return render_template("home.html", td = data)
```

Hi,the reason for your error:
If insert_data(df) is run, your code will run another route, but your data_value() function will run another route.

```
@app.route("/data", methods = ["GET","POST"])
def Insert_data(df):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            d.insert_into_db(df, cursor) 
            print('parsed using normal parsing1_div .')

        except Exception as ex:
            print('db fail1 ')
            print(ex)
        return render_template("index.html")
```

In such cases, you should debug.

If you want to use a function in your view:

view.py

```
@app.route("/abc",method=['GET','POST']):
    ....
    helper.function_name(..)
    return ...
```

helper.py

```
function_name(..):
   ...
   return ..
```